# Canonical bundle of the Lagrangian Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, multilinear-algebra, symplectic-geometry, grassmannian

I'd like to compute the canonical bundle of the Lagrangian Grassmannian $\mathbb{LG}_n$, the set of Lagrangian subspaces  of dimension $n$ of a complex vector space together with fixed symplectic bilinear form. I already know, that this is $K_{\mathbb{LG}_n} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{LG}_n}(-n-1)$.

So far I know, that the tangent space in one point $L$ (that is a Lagrangian subspace) of $\mathbb{LG}_n$ can be identified with the set of symmetric bilinear forms $B_{symm}(L,L)$, see *Piccione, Tausk - A Student's Guide to Symplectic Spaces*.

For some references or help for the proof I'd be grateful.

Comment: Do you mean the real canonical bundle? Then it's trivial if the space is orientable.

Comment: No, I work with complex vector spaces

Comment: @L.Kern I don't understand the question. What do you mean by the "canonical bundle" of the Lagrangian Grassmannian, and what do you mean by "computing" it? I also don't understand the notation $K_{\mathbb{LG}_n}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{LG}_n}( - n - 1)$.

Comment: By canonical bundle I mean the determinant of the sheaf of sections of the cotangent bundle $\det \Omega$ of the Lagrangian grassmannian. This canoncical bundle is denoted by $K$. The line bundle $\mathcal{O}(1)$ denotes the very ample line bundle on $\mathbb{LG}_n$ and $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{LG}_n}(n-1)$ $=$ $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{LG}_n}(1)^{\otimes (n-1)}$. I already know, that the canonical bundle has this kind of look, by 'computing it' I mean proving this statement.